# > Error: schema is invalid: data should be equal to constant in ajv JSON Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv

I'm trying to compare parced JSON to JSON reference by following code:

```
    const Ajv = require("ajv");
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonDataPath, 'utf8'));
    const parsedSchema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonSchemaPath, 'utf8'));
    

    const ajvInstance = Ajv({ allErrors: true });
    const valid = ajvInstance.validate(parsedSchema, parsedData);
    if (valid) {
        console.log("User data is valid");
    } else {
        console.log("User data is INVALID!");
        console.log(ajv.errors);
    }
```

and got following error:

> Error: schema is invalid: data should be equal to constant

As you see, I've tried converting variables to `const`, but it was no help.

Comment: That message does hardly mean that you need to change declarations from `var` to `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because somewhere in your JSON schema you have a definition that field is 'const'. This error is not about your JavaScript code.

> The const keyword is used to restrict a value to a single value.

Read the documentation for examples and for more information [const](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#constant-values)

Comment: That's can be something. I've checked my parsedSchema  data and found to suspicious lines:
``` 
  "config": "Common" ,
  "const":  "First" ,
```
and replaced them with 
```
 "config": { "const": "Common" },
  "const": { "const": "First" },
```
and the error has been thrown again.

I guess that's because of "const" key.

Comment: Also, I have to mention ajv is not working. It's asserting '0' and true and says it's okay, data is valid. Seems to be unable to perform simple task ((

Comment: Mate your parsed data is not good for your schema definition

Comment: `{
  "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "flag": true,
  "myPromises": { "type": "string" },
  "element": { "type": "object" },
  "screenshot": null,
  "elementText": { "type": "string"  },
  "allElementsText": { "type": "string", "pattern": "\\w+const|const+\\w" },
  "counter": {"type" : "integer", "minimum" : 10},
  "config": { "const": "Common" },
  "consst": { "const": "First" },
  "parameters": {"type" : "array", "minItems": 8},
  "description": {"type" : "string", "minLength" : 6, "maxLength" : 14}
}`

Comment: `{
 "flag": "0",
 "myPromises": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
 "element": "title",
 "css": ".dd-ui",
 "screenshot": null,
 "elementText": "browser",
 "allElementsText": "contain the cost",
 "counter": 113,
 "config": "not a Common",
 "const": "the first const",
 "parameters": [ 3, "", "add", "delete", "update", "", 1, false ],
 "description": "my first project on js"

}
 `

Comment: There are the files I'm trying to validate.

Comment: First problem that i see is https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html description that you describe in the schema can only be String because that's like a reserved word in JSON schema definition,